# Does snail cream have a positive impact on the skin?

Tags: medical-science, dermatology

Over the last few years [snail cream](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AK7AV4S) has become a [skin-care phenomenon](http://travel.cnn.com/seoul/shop/snail-cream-821956) in South Korea. Are there any scientific studies analyzing the impact of snail cream on the skin?

[image]

Comment: I can't let this go by, without mentioning [Penn and Teller's take](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2J1bCXpsa0).